# Expo Build Web Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>' react-native-tab-selector

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-web

Built an Expo react app that's currently working on both iOS and android however when I went to build it for the web, it kept showing as a blank screen with the following error:

TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object
[image]

Steps to reproduce:

```
expo build:web
npx serve web-build
```

Answer (score 0):

Was able to fix this by commenting out the exports on the bottom of the `node_modules/react-native-tab-selector/index.js` file:

```
// module.exports = TabSelectorAnimation
// module.exports.default = TabSelectorAnimation
```

When I restarted server and built for web it worked like charm!